# How can I get the `name()` of another ERC721 contract from my contract?

Tags: solidity, nft

Aim: To get the name, symbol and tokenURI of another ERC721 contract from my Solidity contract. The goal is to create a one-click clone of a contract for a microprotocol.

What I've done thus far: `IERC721 getTokenDetails = IERC721(_targetNFT);` - however when I call `getTokenDetails.name()` I get `Member "name" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract IERC721.` - which is expected since `./IERC721.sol` on OpenZeppelin does not have `name()` or `symbol()`

Question: How do I work around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure the target contract contains those functions, you can use the metadata interface: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Metadata.sol

Whenever you know that a contract has some function you want to access, you can either use an existing interface or simply write your own. The interface can contain only the functions you are interested in.

Comment: thank you Lauri, this is excellent. Should I call `IERC721Metadata(_contractAddress)` for this?

Comment: Yes. Just like using any other interface.